# Jquery + webpack4 problems

Tags: jquery, webpack

I tried to google this topic solution but they are all old webpack or not working solution. In the webpack website is also not helpful as well. Please help
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khQ4j.png)

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.js': [
     path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/back-to-top.js')
    ]
 },
 output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
 },
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    })
  ]
};
```

back-to-top.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Back to top
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  // scroll body to 0px on click
  $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
    $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
  });
  $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
});
```

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YslWF.png)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add the error to you question *ask text*. Some people cannot follow links off-site. Also, text in images is often very difficult to read.

Comment: I tried to but the main problem for this stackoverflow is that it can sense the error as the code and when I tried adding both the error and package.json It gives me another problem which is adding more details to the description....HELP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `.tooltip` is a `jQuery` plugin, did you `import`ed it as well?
If so, make sure it was imported before you are running you given code.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which is instead of adding the ProvidePlugin in the plugins, I use this instead

```
externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/